# Swift - Subscribe to Binding Value outside of View

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I need to use UITextField in SwiftUI and I can publish text changes in UITextField to my view model with Binding variable.

But I cannot do the **opposite**. I want to be able to update the UITextField when the variables I publish in the ViewModel change. Because sometimes I want to be able to auto-fill TextFields with the data I pull from the internet.

```
struct Test: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = TestVM()
    var body: some View {
        UIKitField(text: $vm.text)
            .onAppear {
                vm.fetchData()
            }
    }
}

class TestVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""

    func fetchData() {
        text = "abc" // here I want textfield's text to be updated.
    }
}

struct UIKitField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    private let textField = UITextField()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private let parent: UIKitField
        init(_ parent: UIKitField) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
            self.parent.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        }

        @objc func editingChanged() {
            parent.text = parent.textField.text!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `textField's` `text` in [`updateUIView(_:context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/updateuiview(_:context:)).

**From Apple Document:**

> When the state of your app changes, SwiftUI updates the portions of your interface affected by those changes. SwiftUI calls this method for any changes affecting the corresponding UIKit view.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
    guard uiView.text != text else { return } //Change only if it doesn't match
    uiView.text = text
}
```